Issue with Sphere Rotation on Sega Saturn Using Jo Engine
I'm trying to build a simple low-poly sphere that is "playable" using a Sega Saturn gamepad (similar to the game Marble Madness) with Jo Engine, a C engine for Sega Saturn. The code I'm using is as follows:
#include <jo/jo.h>
#include "sphere.h"

jo_camera           cam;
jo_img_8bits        floor_image;
jo_palette          image_pal;
jo_pos3Df           sphere_position = {0, 50, 0};  // Inicializando a posição da esfera
jo_pos3Df           pos;
jo_rot3Df           rot;
jo_rot3Df           sphere_rotation = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};  // Inicializando a rotação da esfera

void my_draw(void) {
    jo_printf(12, 1, "*Simple 3D demo*");
    jo_3d_camera_look_at(&cam);

    jo_3d_push_matrix();
    {
        jo_3d_translate_matrixf(sphere_position.x, sphere_position.y, sphere_position.z);
        jo_3d_rotate_matrix_rad(sphere_rotation.rx, sphere_rotation.ry, sphere_rotation.rz);
        
        display_sphere_mesh();
        jo_3d_set_mesh_texture(&Meshsphere, 0);
    }
    jo_3d_pop_matrix();
}

void my_gamepad(void) {
    const float movement_speed = 1.0f;
    const float rotation_speed = JO_DEG_TO_RAD(5.0f);
    const float DIAGONAL_FACTOR = 0.707f; //(1/sqrt(2))

    float delta_x = 0.0f;
    float delta_z = 0.0f;
    float delta_rx = 0.0f;
    float delta_ry = 0.0f;

    switch (jo_get_input_direction_pressed(0))
    {
        case LEFT:
            delta_x = -movement_speed;
            delta_ry = -rotation_speed;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            delta_x = movement_speed;
            delta_ry = rotation_speed;
            break;
        case UP:
            delta_z = movement_speed;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            delta_z = -movement_speed;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed;
            break;
        case UP_LEFT:
            delta_x = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_z = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_ry = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case UP_RIGHT:
            delta_x = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_z = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_ry = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case DOWN_LEFT:
            delta_x = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_z = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_ry = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case DOWN_RIGHT:
            delta_x = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_z = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_ry = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case NONE:
            return;
    }

    sphere_position.x += delta_x;
    sphere_position.z += delta_z;
    sphere_rotation.rx += delta_rx;
    sphere_rotation.ry += delta_ry;
}

void load_floor_texture(void) {
    pos.x = 800.0;
    pos.y = 800.0;
    pos.z = -35.0;

    rot.rx = JO_DEG_TO_RAD(90.0);
    rot.ry = JO_DEG_TO_RAD(0.0);
    rot.rz = JO_DEG_TO_RAD(0.0);

    jo_core_tv_off();
    jo_enable_background_3d_plane(JO_COLOR_Black);
    jo_tga_8bits_loader(&floor_image, JO_ROOT_DIR, "FLOOR.TGA", 0);
    jo_background_3d_plane_a_img(&floor_image, image_pal.id, true, true);
    jo_core_tv_on();
}

jo_palette *my_tga_palette_handling(void) {
    jo_create_palette(&image_pal);
    return (&image_pal);
}

void draw_3d_planes(void) {
    jo_3d_push_matrix();
    {
        jo_3d_rotate_matrix_rad(rot.rx, rot.ry, rot.rz);
        jo_3d_translate_matrixf(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        jo_background_3d_plane_a_draw(true);
    }
    jo_3d_pop_matrix();
}

void jo_main(void) {
    jo_core_init(JO_COLOR_Black);
    jo_set_tga_palette_handling(my_tga_palette_handling);
    jo_sprite_add_tga(JO_ROOT_DIR, "ROCK.TGA", JO_COLOR_Transparent);
    load_floor_texture();
    jo_3d_camera_init(&cam);
    jo_core_add_callback(my_draw);
    jo_core_add_callback(my_gamepad);
    jo_core_add_callback(draw_3d_planes);
    jo_core_run();
}

the result is:
https://imgur.com/rytTvAq
As you can see, the low-poly sphere is not rotating like a ball when I move the gamepad to the left or right. Instead, it seems to pivot awkwardly or rotate around the wrong axis.
How can I properly implement rotation for a sphere using Jo Engine so that it rotates smoothly like a rolling ball in the correct direction based on the gamepad input?

Not a big issue, you just switched up the Y-Rotation with the Z-Rotation. For rotating a ball on the ground (X/Z-Axis), you don't want to use the vertical axis (which in this case is the Y-Axis). Here is a changed version to reflect my before mentioned changes. Not too much changed, I just renamed delta_ry to delta_rz and added it to the right vector element at the end.
Edit: I added a calculation for the rotation speed, so it can't slide anymore, and reordered the switch statement a bit for visibility.
void my_gamepad(void) {
    const float movement_speed = 1.0f;
    // actually calculate the rotation speed
    // RADIUS NOT KNOWN
    const float rotation_speed = movement_speed / radius;
    const float DIAGONAL_FACTOR = 0.707f; //(1/sqrt(2))

    float delta_x = 0.0f;
    float delta_z = 0.0f;
    float delta_rx = 0.0f;
    float delta_rz = 0.0f;

    switch (jo_get_input_direction_pressed(0))
    {
        case LEFT:
            delta_x = -movement_speed;
            delta_rz = -rotation_speed;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            delta_x = movement_speed;
            delta_rz = rotation_speed;
            break;
        case UP:
            delta_z = movement_speed;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            delta_z = -movement_speed;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed;
            break;
        case UP_LEFT:
            // LEFT
            delta_x = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rz = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            // UP
            delta_z = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case UP_RIGHT:
            // RIGHT
            delta_x = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rz = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            // UP
            delta_z = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case DOWN_LEFT:
            // LEFT
            delta_x = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rz = -rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            // DOWN
            delta_z = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case DOWN_RIGHT:
            // RIGHT
            delta_x = movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rz = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            // DOWN
            delta_z = -movement_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            delta_rx = rotation_speed * DIAGONAL_FACTOR;
            break;
        case NONE:
            return;
    }

    sphere_position.x += delta_x;
    sphere_position.z += delta_z;
    sphere_rotation.rx += delta_rx;
    sphere_rotation.rz += delta_rz;
}


not worked :( the rotations are still not right !

@celsown is it working any better? Why does it not work? Can you please describe it a bit?

@LuigiBro 's answer seems correct, you were rotating around the wrong axis. If the ball is not rotating the correct way but around the correct direction (z), perhaps consider changing the sign ? Anyhow, we need more info to diagnostic better your issue.

No again: https://imgur.com/Cpi1Md0

@celsowm oh my! I mistook an older version of my code for the never one. Let me just quickly fix that. (one thing, you need to manually add the radius, as I don't know it)

@LuigiBro 32 (num of vertices) worked fine, but the diagonals rotations are not good, like a drunken ball

@celsowm So if you move the ball backwards, while it isn't centered in the middle of the screen? Is that what you meant? Or is it just rotating strangely, when inputting a diagonal?

@LuigiBro https://imgur.com/s2gqZMw

@celsowm can you move it in a rectangle formation (not diagonally)? Maybe there is an issue with applying the rotation to the matrix.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
